# Split series in segments larger than a threshold and apply statistics to segments

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series `x` with values `y` and `z`. I would like to get a collection of segments of `x` during which `y` is larger than `0.5`. Over this segment I would like to compute two statistics: the length of the segment in units of `x` and the mean value of `z` over the segment. I want to discard all data for which `y` is 0.5 or less. What is the most elegant way to this with pandas?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.arange(0, 100, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x) + 0.5*np.sin(0.5*x)
z = np.random.rand(x.size)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.stack((x,y), axis=-1), index=x, columns=['y','z'])

# Fetch all x segments for which y is larger than 0.5. Discard others.
# Calculate segment length in units of x.
# Compute mean of z per segment.
```

Comment: have you ever used something like `df[df['y'] > 0.5]`. It isn't entirely clear but you can sum the `index` using `df[df['y'] > 0.5].index.get_values().sum()` the mean is a standard `numpy` function

Comment: Yes, but that does not give me the ability to split out the segments (at least with my pandas knowledge).

Comment: ah ok so by segments you mean continuous sections without a break and you want to apply these operations to these groups individually

Comment: If you plot `y` against `x`, then I would like to have a set of objects, where each object is a continuous time series of `x` points that start when `y` exceeds `0.5` and ends where it goes below `0.5` again. So indeed, I want to apply statistics to the groups separately.

Answer (score 1):

Select values:

```
df = df[df['y'] > 0.5]
```

Spot new segments:

```
df['is_new_segment'] = df.reset_index()['index'].diff() > 0.15
```

Number segments:

```
df['segment'] = df['is_new_segment'].cumsum()
```

Group by segment and apply your function (here `mean` for instance):

```
df.groupby('segment')['z'].mean()
```

Comment: This seems to work, except that your second step is not generic. My true data is a time series which has not equally spaced values.

Comment: Then you should reset the index and (a) work on an integer index to spot segment changes and (b) use the time information in a column for your mean calculations.